# Cannot launch what 3 words intent

Tags: android, android-intent, startactivityforresult

I am trying to open the what3words app using the documentation here

https://developer.what3words.com/tutorial/mobile-linking-to-the-what3words-app/

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("w3w://show?threewords=daring.lion.race"));
startActivityForResult(intent, INTENT_CODE);
```

but I keep getting this issue

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=w3w://show?threewords=daring.lion.race}
```

I am on my device and have google play and the what3words app installed on the device.

Comment: https://developer.what3words.com/support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening the app like this:

```
Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("{w3w package name}");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("w3w://show?threewords=daring.lion.race"));
startActivity(intent);
```

To get the package name look for it in adb:

```
adb shell pm list packages
```